# Extraction of .gz files contained in a folder

Tags: shell

I have a folder containing approximately 320116 .pdb.gz files. I want to uncompress them all. If I use gunzip *.gz it gives me an error i.e. argument list too long. The folder is about 2GB. Please give me an appropriate suggestion.

Comment: If you will have to work on this directory structure on the long term, split this directory in many ones. For example based on files modification time or on files name.

Comment: Yes I do have to work on long term. they have been extracted now I want to subdivide and classify them into three folders on the basis of their names. Is there a shell script to do so?

Comment: I suggest you to search for similar questions there. If you don't find one to suit your needs, ask your own new question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.pdb.gz' -exec gunzip {} +
```

`-exec gunzip {} +` will provide `gunzip` with many but not too many file names on its command line.  This is more efficient than `-exec gunzip {} \;` which starts a new `gunzip` process for each and every file.

Comment: One `find`, fewer `gunzip`!

Comment: Note that the "+" is a GNUism and so will not work on non-GNU systems like *BSD.

Comment: Later versions of BSD `find` allow the "+" notation. See, for example, [the `find` man page for BSD 10.1](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&manpath=FreeBSD+10.1-RELEASE). Also applies to OS X (10.9 and later at least, maybe earlier).

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you get "argument list too long" errors you can work around it by invoking the desired command multiple times, each time with a subset of the arguments you want to use. `xargs` is a tool that helps you do that automatically.

```
find . -type f -a -name \*.pdb.gz -print0 | xargs -0 gunzip
```

Comment: doesn't this have the same inefficiency as `-execdir gunzip "{}" \;` i.e. that xargs will invoke gunzip separately for each file? That is my reading of man page.

Comment: No, `xargs` will stuff as many filenames as will fit on the `gunzip` command line. Try it! `echo a b c d e f | xargs echo` only invokes `echo` once with all 6 arguments so you see one line of output (pretty useless command to execute though!!!!) while if you force `xargs` to only supply up to 3 arguments per invocation of the command using `echo a b c d e f | xargs -n 3 echo` then you get 2 lines of output.

Comment: Another advantage of using `xargs` is that, with the `-P` option, you can run multiple `gunzip` processes in parallel, which (depending on the exact parameters of your system) may go faster.

Comment: thanks for the pointer to `-P`, @psmears. Now *I* learned something too!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
find . -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip {} \;
```

Comment: That will execute `gunzip` once per file. See [John1024's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191141/14034) for a slightly different way that avoids that inefficiency.

Comment: Make sure to escape the \* in \*.gz...

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work, it passes the path/name of each file individually to gunzip for processing:

```
find /my/dir -name "*.pdb.gz" -execdir gunzip "{}" \;
```

Comment: That will execute gunzip once per file. See [John1024's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191141/14034) for a slightly different way that avoids that inefficiency.

Comment: @Celada This was deliberate; my concern was that using + might again lead to an error message because of overloading gunzip. If John1024's method works, it is technically more efficient, but mine should work if his doesn't.

Comment: `find` with `+` and `xargs` are expressly designer with exactly that issue in mind. They will always supply as many arguments as they can, while not exceeding the operating system's limit. Because, by the way, it *is* an operating system limit, nothing to do with `gunzip`.

Comment: @Celada ok thanks for that info, so presumably with '+' gunzip might get invoked more than once, but less than 320,000 times?

Comment: correct‍‍‍‍‍‍‍.

Comment: Make sure to escape the \* in \*.gz...

Comment: @immibis the escaping is not required inside the quotes and indeed will prevent it from working, it would be required if I hadn't used quotes

Comment: @gogoud hmm, I thought "*.pdb.gz" expanded to the quoted names of files matching *.pdb.gz...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multi-core machine you will probably see that using `gunzip` is not going to max out the capabilities of your machine. For that you would need to run multiple `gunzip`s in parallel. To keep track of which are done in which terminal by hand is is cumbersome, but you can easily do that with GNU parallel:

```
find . -name "*.gz" | parallel -X gunzip {}
```

Comment: Won't that fail because the argument list to `parallel` is too long?

Comment: @immibis Yes, I forgot the original problem, I'll update my post

Comment: Won't that *still* fail because the argument list to `find` is too long?

Comment: yes but you're passing all the filenames on `find`'s command line.

Comment: Seems this is not a good day to answer questions, I forgot to quote the argument to `-name`

Answer (score -1):

It is unnecessary to use `find` for this, since you did not mention subfolders. What you need to do is:

```
for f in *.gz;do gunzip $f;done
```

Comment: You **do** need `find` if you don't want to spawn 320116 `gunzip` processes, just like this loop does.